# Can I use Firebase functions to receive data which is supposed to be sent to a server on a port?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a 4G router with GPS functionality. I'd like to save the GPS info so I can keep track of the router as it's mounted on a vehicle.
The GPS configuration needs a server or domain address and a port. I'm wondering if I can set it up to either send the info to Firebase database directly or make sue of functions to achieve this.

I've tried using python with no luck like below :

```
import socket
s = socket.socket() 
s.connect(('host',port))
... etc ...
```

But I think opening a socket won't work.

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging, the realtime database and firestore should all work fine for that, and have resilient fallback. What have you tried?

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide an answer on what would work. But I wrote an answer on why it seems unlikely (to me at least) that Cloud Functions is a feasible solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no generic socket server in Cloud Functions for Firebase. You could point it to a HTTP-triggered Cloud Function, but that'd only work if the GPS device sends HTTP requests, which seems unlikely given that the protocol starts from a socket (instead of a higher level abstraction layer).

Comment: Thanks Frank. It asks for domain or server address. I guess I have to try pointing it to a function and see if it triggers it. Will update my question with more info as I go on